# Realm Database, can i use crud?

Tags: android, realm

I saw at the GITHUB to ask here..

Old SQLIte i used to create a CRUD service for doing database operations.. now its kindly diferent, why? because i should remember to call `realm.close();`

i have at least 4 activites, 10 fragments, 10 async tasks and other things, and EACH one has a kind of database operation, if i need to call realm.close

i should create a CRUD, and pass the `realm` and use it to do the operations?

my actual code look like this:

```
static LOperations instance;
private Realm realm;
private RealmQuery<L> query;
private RealmResults<Category> categories;
private L lObject;

public LOperations(Application application) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}


public static LOperations with(Activity activity) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LOperations(activity.getApplication());
    }
    return instance;
}

public static LOperations with(Application application) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LOperations(application);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static LOperations with(Fragment fragment) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LOperations(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
public RealmResults<Lei> getAllLbyCategory(String c) {
    query = realm.where(L.class);
    query.equalTo("active", 1);
    query.contains("category", c);
    return  query.findAllSorted("id", Sort.ASCENDING);

}

@Override
public RealmResults<Category> getAllCategories() {
    return realm.where(Category.class).equalTo("active", true).findAllSorted("order", Sort.ASCENDING);
}

@Override
public RealmResults<Lei> getAllActiveL() {

    query = realm.where(L.class);
    query.equalTo("active", 1);
    return query.findAllSorted("last_date", Sort.ASCENDING);

}
```

this work perfectly, but i cant understand how can i TRACK the opened databases?

actually i use this: `LOperations.with(this/getActivity).someMethod();` (by doing this i think i cant track the opened realms)

i can think in something about this:

```
Realm realm = realm.getDefaultInstance();

and to get allActiveL(), change to:

  @Override
    public RealmResults<Lei> getAllActiveL(Realm realm) {

        realm.where(L.class);
        query.equalTo("active", 1);
        return query.findAllSorted("last_date", Sort.ASCENDING);

    }
```

so i have the realm created and then pass it to the METHOD, so i can add the realm.close() at the onDestroy

is that the correct approach? or is there another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your `LOperations` would only work on the thread where you first create the instance on, and then it wouldn't work on any other threads (it's prone to break in `doInBackground()`)

Currently my repositories all have a `Realm` parameter to them and are singleton. Another possible approach would be to create a repository whereever you need it and the instance is passed to it on creation (and the instance is closed at the execution of the thread).

```
public interface RealmRepository<T extends RealmObject, ID> {
    String getIdFieldName();

    T findOne(Realm realm, ID id);

    RealmResults<T> findAll(Realm realm);

    T saveOrUpdate(Realm realm, T t);

    RealmList<T> saveOrUpdate(Realm realm, RealmList<T> tList);

    RealmQuery<T> query(Realm realm);

    void delete(Realm realm, ID id);

    void delete(Realm realm, T t);

    void deleteAll(Realm realm, RealmResults<T> realmResults);

    void deleteEveryObject(Realm realm);

    long count(Realm realm);
}
```

Personally I use a [single Realm for the UI thread](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/realmbookexample/application/RealmManager.java), and create Realm instance for background threads with finally to close.

But generally, `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` work for activities, `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()` for normal fragments, personally I do [`constructor` and `onDestroy()` for retained fragments](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/realmbookexample/paths/books/BooksScopeListener.java).

And for async task,

```
public void MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Void doInBackground(Void... nothing) {
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            //...
        } finally {
            if(realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        // use realm on UI thread
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void results) {
        // use realm on UI thread            
    }
}
```